# Sharing PC internet via wifi

Tags: wireless-networking

I  have a TP-Link TD-8815 Adsl2 + Modem router which is not wifi and it's connected to my PC with rj45.

Since i need to connect my laptop to it too i wonder, **is there any way to share it via wifi**? like something connected to my PC and create a Hotspot?

Thanks

P.S i prefer to not use wifi modem that's why i'm asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure... there are a number of applications, depending on the OS, that will [make your PC a Wi-Fi hot-spot.](http://www.howtogeek.com/214080/how-to-turn-your-windows-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/) The reference mentions *Connectify*, which I've used to bridge PC to tablet, but there are [many alternative](http://alternativeto.net/software/connectify/)s.

If you're using Windows 10 v. 1607 or later [to check, at a CMD prompt type *winver*], Wi-Fi connection sharing is built-in.

Be aware, though, that a PC serving as a Wi-Fi router is a potential security hazard. Check what level of encryption is available and keep use to a minimum. Running the hot-spot for a few hours in a rural setting is probably OK, but leaving it on full-time in an urban setting is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thank you sir.  i don't have enough reputation to mark it as right answer.